# Why does Arch's libcairo grayscale antialiasing, when Ubuntu's uses subpixel?

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, fonts, cairo

[SciTE](https://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) uses Cairo. On Ubuntu, it uses subpixel antialiasing, which I like.
But unfortunately, on Arch Linux, it uses grayscale antialiasing, which I find too blurry for me.

I already spent hours messing with `fonts.conf` and such, to no avail.
Turns out the problem isn't with my configuration.

But then I suddenly discovered that **merely copying** `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2` from Ubuntu to `/usr/bin/libcairo.so.2` on Arch Linux resolves the problem. So, clearly, that file is the root cause.

So, I have two questions:

1. What is Ubuntu doing differently that causes this?
   Checking the [patches](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/cairo/cairo_1.16.0-5ubuntu2.debian.tar.xz), I don't see any customizations that seem related to antialiasing.
2. What is the *proper* way to fix this on Arch?